# Using a variable in HTML without Javascript

Tags: html

I have this HTML code:

```
<body>
<table width="650">
<tr width="650">
<td width="650">
lots of text here
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

How can I use a variable/constant to represent 650? Do I need to use javascript or something?

**What I really want is a way to reuse some code so that I only need to change the width value in one place.**

Nb. I'm not using a database or anything. Just a simple html page, so I'd like to do something like:
int x = 650

Comment: Where would the value of the variable come from? Can you use server-side scripting for it, like PHP?

Comment: Hi Barmar, please see my edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using css:

```
table,tr,td{width:650px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS

```
table, tr, td {
    width: 650px;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            lots of text here
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: I do not think this is an answer to the question, as they are asking how to use a variable for the width of the table/tr.

Comment: See the edit to the question, he just wants a way that he can change the value in one place. This solves that problem.