# HTML: storing code for reuse as a variable

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I would like to store a value in a single place so that I do not have to type it over and over again inside an HTML document. No database or PHP or anything like that.

For example's sake, think about something like this:

HTML

```
<!-- Desktop -->
<div class="desktop">
<p>Hello world.</p>
</div>

<!-- Tablet -->
<div class="tablet">
<p>Hello world.</p>
</div>

<!-- Mobile -->
<div class="mobile">
<p>Hello world.</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.desktop { color: blue }
.tablet { color: red }
.mobile { color: green}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
.tablet, .mobile { display: none; }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 999px) {
.desktop, .mobile { display: none; }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.desktop, .tablet { display: none; }
}
```

I would like to set a variable equal to `<p>Hello world.</p>` so that if I needed to use it more than once, I wouldn't have to repeat it over and over again.

This would be applicable to more scenarios than just media queries (for example, referencing a frequently-updated URL in different locations inside a large document).

I get the impression from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22002251/using-a-variable-in-html-without-javascript) that this is not possible in pure HTML.

If this cannot be done in just HTML, how could it be done with Javascript + HTML?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are looking for something like a [templating engine](https://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/preprocessors/) or an [HTML preprocessor](https://colorlib.com/wp/top-templating-engines-for-javascript/)

Basically the idea is you write your code in something that is readable/simple and then the preprocessor/templating engine "compiles" that into the code that can run in browsers (rather than building a page at runtime like PHP).

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript DOM Api.
You can dynamically add or remove attributes of html elements.

Comment: Something like this?

```<p id="p1">Hello world.</p>

<script>
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML
</script>```

Comment: yea you can make components out like that and dynamically inject them when needed. Although doing this on your own is a bit overhead. Try using any framework if you really want reusable components or maybe web components.

Answer (score 0):

```
I would like to set a variable equal to <p>Hello world.</p>
```

For this scenario, you can use HTML templates. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_template.asp

Alternatively you can have a div which is hidden in page, and you can save value as attribute value or content.

```
<div id="someid" value="my data"> Some other data </div>
```

But, Both methods need to have minimal work in Javascript.